# I keep failing to understand what I'm doing wrong - derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I need to find the derivative of this function:

$f(x)=x^2(x-2)^4$

I have gone about this two ways:

1. Chain Rule inside a Power Rule

$$f(x)=x^2(x-2)^4$$
(I found the derivative of $(x-2)^4$ using the chain rule.)
$$f'(x)=(x^2)(4)(x-2)^3(1)+(x-2)^4(2x)$$
$$f'(x)=4x^2(x-2)^3+2x(x-2)^4$$

2. Power Rule only

$$f(x)=x^2(x-2)^4$$
$$f'(x)=(x^2)(4(x-2)^3)+(x-2)^4(2x)$$
$$f'(x)=4x^2(x-2)^3+2x(x-2)^4$$

My calculator gives me the same answer that I get in method 2. However the textbook says the answer to this problem is $2x(x-2)^3(3x-2)$

So, assuming the textbook is correct (it better be), what are my calculator and I doing wrong? Also, why does the using the chain rule inside of the power rule produce a different result? I only ask the second question because I was under the impression that the chain rule was just another shortcut for finding derivatives.

Comment: The result is the same, as the answer below put it. The way 3×2+10 and 8×2 are same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both terms in $4x^2(x-2)^3+2x(x-2)^4$ are multiples of $2x$ and $(x-2)^3$.  So factor them out:
$$
4x^2(x-2)^3+2x(x-2)^4 = 2x(x-2)^3[2x+(x-2)] = 2x(x-2)^3(3x-2)
$$

Comment: Wait is that really all I forgot to do...

I do find it interesting though, because I took my answer (from method 2) and subtracted the textbooks answer from it (my calculator has CAS), and it didn't produce the expected result of 0. I know you can't rely on a calculator, but it can be very helpful for checking answers of course.

Comment: Yep, that's all there is to it.  I can't explain why your calculator did what it did.  Maybe it wouldn't simplify the difference (to zero) unless you tell it to?  Another check would be to graph the two functions and see if the graphs align.

Comment: Good point. Also, maybe this is a bit much to ask, but do you think you could expand the steps to what you did in your answer? I don't know why, maybe I don't know how, or maybe I forgot, but I can't quite figure out _how_ you did that. Like, I can see the 2x and (x-2)^3 inside both terms, but I don't quite remember how to factor them out, then combine them into the final answer. WAIT, nevermind ha. I did it. Just needed some scratch paper to work it out.

Comment: Guess I'll have to ask the teacher to clarify what the point of the Chain Rule is tomorrow. Thanks for the help with this problem though Matthew. I was actually having an identical problem with some other problems in the textbook, but I guarantee the same solution is there.

Comment: @Magicrafter13Gaming You'll know what the chain rule is about when you'll have to consider the derivative of $\log\lvert\sin x\rvert$ or more complicated functions.

Answer (score 0):

f(x) = X²(x-2)^4

In this question, U will have to apply products rule and Chain rule

Let U = x²
V= (x-2)^4

du/dx = 2x

But, V is a function of function, so to differentiate
This, 
Let x-2 = g

So, V=g^4

dg/dx = 1

dv/dg = 4g³

So,  dv/dx =dv/dg × dg/dx

So, dv/dx = 4g³ ×1

Since g= x-2

dv/dx = 4(x-2)³

So back to our dy/dx

dy/dx = Udv/dx + Vdu/dx

Our U=x², V = (x-2)^4

du/dx = 2x , dv/dx = 4(x-2)³

dy/dx = x² (4(x-2)³) + (x-2)^4(2x)

dy/dx = 4x²(x-2)³ + 2x(x-2)^4

Factorise

dy/dx = 2x(x-2)³ (2x +(x-2)

dy/dx = 2x(x-2)³(3x-2)

So, ur textbook is correct, and u are also correct. Your textbook only simplified further by factorising.

And, as for ur second question, Each formula in differentiation has its uses,  Quotient Rule for quotient, Product rule for product questions and Chain Rule for Function of a function question, u can't interchange them.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Also, we use formal English words like *you* and *your*.